# Can there be two cases of pronoun in a sentence?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, possessive-determiners, objective-case

"She is doing her best to do the job"

The pronoun "her" is confusing me, it could be either in objective case 'cause it acts as object complement or in possessive case 'cause it modifies the noun "best"

Comment: Yes, a sentence may have two or more pronouns. When you say that "her" is confusing you, do you mean that you don't understand what the sentence means, or that you don't know how to analyse the grammar?

Comment: "Her" is a genitive case pronoun. It doesn't modify "best", but functions as a determiner to it.

Comment: 'her' is not a pronoun in this occurrence, it is an [adjective](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/possessives-adjectives). Also see idiom [to do one's best](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do%20one%27s%20best) : I do *my* best, you do *your* best, etc.